# Unicode code string

Tags: java, string, unicode

I want to create a string that will contain unicode code, but won't convert it on use.

```
String s = new String("\u010C");
System.out.println(s);
```

I want this to be output:

```
\u010C
```

instead of this:

```
Č
```

I want string to actually contain that set of six characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the output to be

```
\u010C
```

You need to escape your backslash:

```
String s = new String("\\u010C");
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keppil’s answer is obviously the correct one.  To display the 4-digit hex number for a given character, you can also do:

```
System.out.println(String.format("\\u%04x", (int)'Č'));
```